# how to stop autocomplete from working on a specific form field

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete

this is my form field:

```
.country.booking-field = passenger.select :country,
                         Country.all.pluck(:name),
                         {prompt: t('booking.country')},
                         autocomplete: 'false',
                         class: "country tt-input select-beast"
```

I tried to stop the autocomplete from completing the country field, but the field is still autocompleted. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known error, I am not sure why it happens but it can be a really annoying thing to work out, using `autocomplete: 'false'`or `autocomplete: 'off'` doesn't work.

The only known method is to use `autocomplete: 'new-password'`

I know that this works for plain HTML, it might not work for whatever language you're using, but it is definitely worth a try!

Cheers.